# Detecting clicks with a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

Find myself writing an extension for Chrome, as a test I want to make this happen:

```
$(document).click(function(e) { alert('clicked'); });
```

But it does not work as expected, any ideas?

This is manifest.json:

```
"name": "Test",
  "version": "0.2",
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/mail/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.js", "test.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: How are you injecting that code into the website? Are you using a content_scripts value, permissions value or a programmatic injection? Maybe this resource will help you: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: see edit, test.js file is present up and running when executing clicks, but no alert whatsoever.

Comment: Have you tried changing your matches to a simpler website? It could be something related to gmail. If you can narrow it down to that it may be easier to help you.

Comment: Changed "all_frames" to true, in order to get loaded in every frame of Gmail, works but not perfectly. e.g. when clicking on compose it does not fire the alert

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(e) { var evt=e||window.event;if(evt.type=='click')alert('clicked'); });
```

Here is what you are missing!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bxqmL/2/)

Comment: jQuery does all of that for you already.  And adding `if` statements won't make more code run.

Comment: @SLaks I know, but I was only trying to make the code work for him!!

Comment: @jacktrades Click on the DEMO link i pasted over there (or here once more and click on the right hand side box) http://jsfiddle.net/bxqmL/2/

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `.on()` it worked for me. Simple example: `$(document).on("click",function(){alert("clicked")});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

For all options of `.on` look here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: So can you write some more details of what you want to achieve? Because  if you want to alert every time when you click anywhere on the page, I have tried it in my website, and it works perfectly